# Adding Image in excel using pyexcelerate

Tags: python, pyexcelerate

I am using [pyexcelerate](https://pypi.org/project/PyExcelerate/) library to generate an excel sheet in python. I need to add an image at the top using an image url but I could not find any solution for that library. Can anyone tell whether its possible to add image using pyexcelerate?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid, this isn't possible. The library ***pyexcelerate*** is aiming to fast writing data. If you want add an image, use an different library, for example ***openpyxl***:
 https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html?highlight=image#inserting-an-image